# How to bind to the latest element in collection at XAML without additional converters and properties

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I need to bind to first and last element in collection.
First is an easy task = {Binding Items[0]}
But last one is another thing - I tried like Items[Items.Count-1] but have no luck.

Items - List

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that you can use only absolute indexer values like Items[2].
The only solution is to customize bindings (converters, additional properties, etc)